# How can I fix the segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to manipulate the linked list?

Tags: c

This code is supposed to add two polynomials and looks correct but causes a core dumped error.In the sum function, when I put "polynomial1" as the 1st argument of the sum function and "polynomial2" as the 2nd argument,the code does not present a segmentation error but gives a false result.Indeed the sum function is not carried out and the "polynomail2" is return as result of the addition of the two polynomials. But when I put "polynomial2" as 1st argument of the sum function, it causes a segmentation error! I've been on this for days.Can you help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
typedef struct Polynome *Poly;
struct Polynome{
    int degre;
    float coef;
    struct Polynome *suivant;
};

Poly new()
{
    return NULL;
}
int vide(Poly p)        // tester si un polynome est vide
{
    return p == NULL;   // renvoi 1 si c'est vide
}
/*Poly *monome(float coef,int degre)
{
    if(degre<0){printf("Erreur!! Puissance négative");return NULL;}
    else
    {
        Poly *p;
        p=(Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));
        p->coef=coef;
        p->degre=degre;
        p->suivant=NULL;
        return p;
    }
}*/

Poly ajouteMonome(Poly polynome,float coef,int degre)
{
    Poly tmp;
    tmp=malloc(sizeof(Poly));
    tmp->coef=coef;
    tmp->degre=degre;
    tmp->suivant=polynome;
    return tmp;
}

Poly comp(Poly p1,Poly p2)
{
    if(p1!=NULL && p1->degre!=p2->degre)
    {
        ajouteMonome(p2,p1->coef,p1->degre);
        p1=p1->suivant;
        p2=p2->suivant;
        comp(p1,p2);
    }
    else if(p1!=NULL && p1->degre==p2->degre)
    {
        p1=p1->suivant;
        p2=p2->suivant;
        comp(p1,p2);
    }
}

Poly somme(Poly polynome2,Poly polynome1)
{
    Poly sommeu;
    Poly polynome2copie;
    polynome2copie=polynome2;
    //sommeu=malloc(sizeof(Poly));
    //sommeu=new();
    if(polynome1!=NULL)
    {
        if(polynome2!=NULL)
        {
            if(polynome1->degre==polynome2->degre)
            {
                ajouteMonome(sommeu,polynome1->coef+polynome2->coef,polynome1->degre);
                //printf("Ok");
                polynome1=polynome1->suivant;
                polynome2=polynome2copie;
                somme(polynome1,polynome2);
            }
            else
            {
                //polynome1=polynome1->suivant;
                polynome2=polynome2->suivant;
                somme(polynome1,polynome2);
            }
            /*else if(polynome1->degre>polynome2->degre)
            {
                //ajouteMonome(sommeu,polynome1->coef,polynome1->degre);
                //printf("OK");
                polynome2=polynome2->suivant;
                somme(polynome1,polynome2);
            }
            else if(polynome1->degre<polynome2->degre)
            {
                //ajouteMonome(sommeu,polynome2->coef,polynome2->degre);
                polynome2=polynome2->suivant;
                somme(polynome1,polynome2);
            }*/
        }
        else if(polynome2==NULL)
        {
            ajouteMonome(sommeu,polynome1->coef,polynome1->degre);
            polynome1=polynome1->suivant;
            polynome2=polynome2copie;
            somme(polynome1,polynome2);
        }

    }
    else if(polynome1==NULL)
    {
        polynome2=polynome2copie;
        comp(polynome2,sommeu);
    }

    return sommeu;
}

void afficher(Poly polynome)
{
    if (vide(polynome))
    {
        printf(" Liste vide \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(polynome->suivant==NULL)
    {
        if(polynome->coef!=0 && polynome->degre>1)
        {
            printf("%fX^%d ",polynome->coef,polynome->degre); 
        }   
        else if(polynome->coef!=0 && polynome->degre==1)
        {
            printf("%fX ",polynome->coef); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(polynome->coef!=0 && polynome->degre>1)
        {
            printf("%fX^%d+ ",polynome->coef,polynome->degre);
            afficher(polynome->suivant);    
        } 
        else if(polynome->coef!=0 && polynome->degre==1)
        {
            printf("%fX+ ",polynome->coef);
            afficher(polynome->suivant);  
        }
    }  
}

/*void saisie(Poly *polynome)
{
    int rep;
    float coef;
    int degre;
    do{
        printf("Coefficient: ");
        scanf("%f",&coef);
        if(coef!=0)
        {
            printf("Dégré: ");
            scanf("%d",&degre);
            polynome=ajouteMonome(polynome,coef,degre);
        }
        printf("Continuer? 0/1 : ");
        scanf("%d",&rep);
    }while(rep==1);
}*/

int main()
{
    Poly polynome1=malloc(sizeof(Poly));
    Poly polynome2=malloc(sizeof(Poly));
    Poly sommefinale=malloc(sizeof(Poly));
    polynome1=new();
    polynome2=new();
    sommefinale=new();
    //int rep;
    //float coef;
    //int degre;
    //printf("Entrez les coefficients et dégré du premier polynôme:\n");
    polynome1=ajouteMonome(polynome1,2,4);
    polynome1=ajouteMonome(polynome1,3,3);
    polynome1=ajouteMonome(polynome1,7,2);
    polynome1=ajouteMonome(polynome1,8,1);
    polynome1=ajouteMonome(polynome1,1,5);
    //if(polynome1==NULL){printf("P1 est vide");}else{printf("P1 n'est pas vide");}
    //saisie(polynome1);
    /*do{
        printf("Coefficient: ");
        scanf("%f",&coef);
        if(coef!=0)
        {
            printf("Dégré: ");
            scanf("%d",&degre);
            polynome1=ajouteMonome(polynome1,coef,degre);
        }
        printf("Continuer? 0/1 : ");
        scanf("%d",&rep);
    }while(rep==1);*/

    printf("\nP1: ");
    afficher(polynome1);
    
    //printf("\nEntrez les coefficients et dégré du deuxième polynôme:\n");
    polynome2=ajouteMonome(polynome2,5,3);
    polynome2=ajouteMonome(polynome2,4,2);
    polynome2=ajouteMonome(polynome2,8,1);
    //saisie(polynome2);
    /*do{
        printf("Coefficient: ");
        scanf("%f",&coef);
        if(coef!=0)
        {
            printf("Dégré: ");
            scanf("%d",&degre);
            polynome2=ajouteMonome(polynome2,coef,degre);
        }
        printf("Continuer? 0/1 : ");
        scanf("%d",&rep);
    }while(rep==1);*/

    printf("\nP2: ");
    afficher(polynome2);

    sommefinale=somme(polynome1,polynome2);
    printf("\nLa somme donne : ");
    //if(sommefinale==NULL){printf("Sfinale est vide");}else{printf("Sfinale n'est pas vide");}
    afficher(sommefinale);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Poly polynome1=malloc(sizeof(Poly));` allocates memory and assigns it's address to the pointer. `polynome1=new();` assigns NULL to the pointer and leaks the previously allocated memory. This is in addition to allocating the wrong amount of memory as noted in an answer.

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings. Line 59: `'comp' must return a value.` Line 74: `uninitialized local variable 'sommeu' used.`

Comment: okay,thanks for your contribution!